# IllegalMonthError in Python datefinder

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, jupyter-notebook, datefinder

I am trying to extract dates from email texts using `datefinder` python library.

Below is a the code snippet of what I am trying to do.

```
import datefinder

#body has list of email texts

email_dates=[]
for b in body: 
    dates = datefinder.find_dates(b)
    date = []
    for d in dates:
        date.append(d)

    email_dates.append(date)
```

datefinder tries to construct all the numbers in the email to dates. I get lot of false positives. I can remove those using some logic. But i get `IllegalMonthError` in some email and i am unable to go past the error and retrieve dates from other emails. Below is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalMonthError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    654         try:
--> 655             ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
    656         except ValueError as e:

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in _build_naive(self, res, default)
   1237 
-> 1238             if cday > monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]:
   1239                 repl['day'] = monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]

c:\python\python38\lib\calendar.py in monthrange(year, month)
    123     if not 1 <= month <= 12:
--> 124         raise IllegalMonthError(month)
    125     day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)

IllegalMonthError: bad month number 42; must be 1-12

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-1fbacc8ca3f6> in <module>
      7     dates = datefinder.find_dates(b)
      8     date = []
----> 9     for d in dates:
     10         date.append(d)
     11 

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\datefinder\__init__.py in find_dates(self, text, source, index, strict)
     30         ):
     31 
---> 32             as_dt = self.parse_date_string(date_string, captures)
     33             if as_dt is None:
     34                 ## Dateutil couldn't make heads or tails of it

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\datefinder\__init__.py in parse_date_string(self, date_string, captures)
    100         # otherwise self._find_and_replace method might corrupt them
    101         try:
--> 102             as_dt = parser.parse(date_string, default=self.base_date)
    103         except (ValueError, OverflowError):
    104             # replace tokens that are problematic for dateutil

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1372         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1373     else:
-> 1374         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1375 
   1376 

c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    655             ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
    656         except ValueError as e:
--> 657             six.raise_from(ParserError(e.args[0] + ": %s", timestr), e)
    658 
    659         if not ignoretz:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Suppose if i am getting this error in the 5th email, I will not be able to retrieve dates from 5th onwards. How to bypass this error, remove the entries causing this error and retrieve all other dates?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share a string that generates this error?

Comment: @snakecharmerb: `Liverpool NY 13088 42 cases` This is the string which caused the error

Comment: It looks to be the same as [this dateutil bug](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/1038); the issue asserts that it was fixed in dateutil 2.8.1 but it can be reproduced with the string you provided.  So I guess you just have to wrap it in a try/except for now.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks so much. This helped e to add `try except` block wiser.

Comment: (It seems that I misread the issue, and the fix [will actually land in 2.8.2](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/1038#issuecomment-809975251) (as yet unreleased)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `try/except` block:

```
try:
    datefinder.find_dates(b)
except IllegalMonthError as e:
    # this will print the error, but will not stop the program
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    # any other unexpected error will be propagated
    raise e
```

**Update** from the edits:

Notice that the traceback shows

```
----> 9     for d in dates:
```

that the exeption is raised here. Indeed, checking the documentations for [`find_dates`](https://datefinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#datefinder.find_dates), you see that `find_dates` returns a generator:

> Returns a generator that produces datetime.datetime objects, or a
> tuple with the source text and index, if requested

So the actual parsing of the date is not done when you call `find_dates`, but when you iterate over the results. This makes it trickier to wrap in a `try/catch`, as you have to iterate over the generator item by item, each in a separate `try/catch` block:

```
from datefinder import find_dates

string_with_dates = """
...
entries are due by January 4th, 2017 at 8:00pm
...
created 01/15/2005 by ACME Inc. and associates.
...
Liverpool NY 13088 42 cases
"""

matches = find_dates(string_with_dates)
print(type(matches))  # <class 'generator'>

while True:

    try:
        m = next(matches)

    # this is the exception seen by the program, rather than IllegalMonthError
    except TypeError as e:
        print(f"TypeError {e}")
        continue

    # the generator has no more items
    except StopIteration as e:
        print(f"StopIteration {e}")
        break

    # any other unexpected error will be propagated
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    print(f"m {m}")
```

You can do with `m` whatever you need.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: tried adding `try except` block for `dates = datefinder.find_dates(b)` and also for `dates.append(d)`. Getting exactly the same error.

Comment: In the traceback you posted there is no information about which line of your code raises the exception. Are you sure that it's raised in this snippet?

Comment: Updated the traceback. I missed this. Thanks

Comment: That was crucial, I have updated the answer with more insights.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This helps. Accepted this answer

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `if` statement checking whether the given month is within the range of `1-12`, and if it is, only then append to `date`.